# objJSO.importXFAData not writing data to PDF form

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

The following code will open and save the testing PDF in question, but will not write any of the values in the XML file referenced into the saved form. The PDF was created by Livecycle, hence the XFA reference in the code. For the life of me, I cannot figure out why this command is not executing and not returning an error if it is somehow faulty.

```
    Sub LoopTrial()

Dim strPDFPath As String
Dim MyFile As String

    MyPath = "H:\Testing\Forms\"

strPDFPath = "H:\Testing\Test Form.pdf"

myExtension = "1.xml"


MyFile = MyPath & myExtension

'Loop
'Do While MyFile <> ""

        Set objAcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
        Set objAcroAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
        If objAcroAVDoc.Open(strPDFPath, "") = True Then
            Set objAcroPDDoc = objAcroAVDoc.GetPDDoc
            Set objJSO = objAcroPDDoc.GetJSObject
        End If


    objJSO.importXFAData MyFile

    i = i + 1
   strPDFOutPath = "H:\Testing\Forms\Form" & i & ".pdf"
   objAcroPDDoc.Save 1, strPDFOutPath
   objAcroApp.Exit

'Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: For reference, here is the full text of the XML file in question - I have tested it from within Acrobat and the manual import there works fine and inserts the values: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Form1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Page1>
  <FirstName>Brandon</FirstName>
  <LastName>Stark</LastName>
  <Home>Winterfell</Home>
  <Fate>Three-Eyed Raven</Fate>
 </Page1>
</Form1>

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, the importXFAData method is only allowed in batch and console events. You won't be able to execute it directly via VBA. You'll need to create a trusted function first and load it as an application level JavaScript, then call the trusted function. You'll also need to convert your path that will be a parameter for the JSO from Windows format to one that Acrobat JavaScript will understand... something like...

"C/foo/data.xfa"

for...

"C:\foo\data.xfa"

To create a trusted function, create a JavaScript (.js) file and load it into the Acrobat application JavaScript folder. It will look like this...

```
trustedImportXFAData = app.trustedFunction( function (pathToXFA)
{
      // Additional code may appear above
      app.beginPriv();    // Explicitly raise privilege
      this.importXFAData(pathToXFA); //"this" being the form document
      app.endPriv();
      // Additional code may appear below.
})
```

The from VBA you'll call it the same way.

```
objJSO.trustedImportXFAData MyFile
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for answering! I really hope this works. 

Because I am a javascript know-nothing, please help me stumble through the script you've provided. 

I'm assuming that for "this.importXFAData(pathToXFA)" will the JavaScript still have access to the variables I have already defined in the rest of the VBA script, or do I need to define the paths all over again? Running it as you have it written, it returns an error "Object doesn't support this property or method" so it doesn't look like it picked up on "this" when it ran.

Comment: Ack! - There was a typo in my script. The comment after line 4 wasn't properly commented. I only had one slash. I've edited the answer. Try it again.

Comment: I've made the change, but am still receiving the same error after trying both your edited version and having removed all comments entirely. "Object doesn't support this property or method"